# Connecting to a windows server and run commands from local computer

Tags: python, node.js, windows, cmd, remote-desktop

I want to connect to a Windows server and run commands there using cmd or python or nodejs.

I usually connect via remote desktop tool which will take to an another windows just to check for windows services status.

Comment: So, why can't you connect to Windows server using rdp?

Comment: I am trying to write a script which will check all the services in the Remote windows server and get back the results.
Instead of logging into the Windows server and perform all the tasks

Comment: See `sc /?` (you don't need to run programs on servers to check services status) and `wmic /node:127.0.0.1 Process Call Create "C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe`

Comment: @Noodles : How will i connect to the Remote server which is in an another data center.

Comment: One reason Windows separates local system calls (e.g. `NtCreateKey`) from user-mode APIs (e.g. `RegCreateKey`) is to allow remote procedure calls (e.g. `RegConnectRegistry` or command-line `reg.exe query \\SystemName\HKLM\...`). For services [`OpenSCManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684323) allows connecting to a remote system. From the command line, use `sc.exe \\SystemName [command] ...`.